# How to make ZedGraph bars overlap?

Tags: c#, zedgraph

For a particular task, I need bars on my bar graph to overlap.  Currently, if two bars from two different data sets have the same x value, they are set apart from each other instead of both originating at the actual x value.

How can I force ZedGraph to add bars that land exactly on their x values, even if there is more than one bar with the same x value.  When they're separated, they're not even moved from the actual x value by the same amount, so it just looks really bad.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default format for bar charts is `BarType.Cluster`, but it seems you probably want `BarType.Overlay`.

Try setting the following property:

```
zedGraphControl1.GraphPane.BarSettings.Type = BarType.Overlay;
```

Reference: [Zedgraph at CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/zedgraph.aspx)